# vector push_back zero into an empty vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl, stdvector

I encountered the following property of `std::vector` that I did not know and I was wondering if someone could clarify it for me.

I think this code:

```
int main()
{
  int i = 5; 
  vector<int> vector;
  while(i > 0){
    vector.push_back(i);
    --i;
  }
}
```

should produce a vector with the following elements:

```
5, 4, 3, 2, 1
```

However, when I run the code above what I get is:

```
5, 4, 3, 2, 0
```

In order to explore what is going on I printed the vector at each stage and I get the following sequence:

- i=5  -- vector (0)
- i=4 -- vector(5, 0)
- i=3 -- vector(5, 4, 0)
- i=2 -- vector(5, 4, 3, 0)
- i=1 -- vector(5, 4, 3, 2, 0)

So I think somehow a zero gets push_backed in the first cycle (where 5 should be) which is very strange. If I try a bigger (say n=10) then the last element is modified every time cycle.

I do not understand what's going. My guess is that there is something in the buffer maybe that get's push back before 5 and then this puts the push back and the cycle out of phase. Or is it something else?

---

Edit:

---

So as people kindly pointed out -or implied- in the comments the error was in the printing routine that I was used. For the record it was:

```
void print_vector(std::vector<int> vector){
  cout << string(10, '-') << endl;
  cout << "("; 
  for(int i=0; i < vector.size() - 1; ++i){
    cout << vector[i] << ", ";
  }
  cout << vector[vector.size()];
  cout << ")" << endl;

}
```

And the mistakes comes from the `vector[vector.size()]` which does weird things when the vector does not have elements I guess.

Comment: Can you show us the printing code too? MVCE would be ideal.

Comment: This is not the code you're running. See: http://ideone.com/b1qxSV

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/lcCxgb) if I add code to print the vector at each stage. Please add the code you use to print it, to make a complete test case.

Comment: I suppose an answer should tell you "where did I go wrong?". Post the complete code and your environment.

Comment: `vector[vector.size()]` is always illegal and results in undefined behaviour, as it tries to acces one-past-end element of the vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your error is indeed in the printing code. The

```
vector[vector.size()]
```

expression is illegal in C++. Vector contains elements in range *[0;`vector.size()`)*, and the expression tries to access the non-existent. one-past-end element of the vector, which is undefined behavior.